# internet explorer 7 css width 100% problem

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

How can I fix this...

Here is my screen on IE7[image: Screen on IE7]

And here it is on IE8
[image: Screen on IE8]

My css code here is..

```
#content{
    font-family:Arial;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 5em;
    display: table-cell;
    /*vertical-align: middle;*/
    text-align: center;
}

#main_content{
    font-family:Arial;
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    background-color: #f8f8f8; 
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -45%;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
}

#main_content table{
    font-family:Arial;
    width: inherit;
    border:solid thin #dedede;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    text-align:left;
    /*margin-bottom: 5%;*/
    padding-left: 2px;
}

#main_content table tr td{
    font-family:Arial;
    border:solid thin #dedede;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    padding:0;
    text-align:left;
    padding-left: 2px;
}

#main_content table tr td input, #main_content table tr td select, #main_content table tr td textarea{
    font-family:Arial;
    width:94%;
    text-align:left;
    border: none;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding: 2% 2% 2% 2%;
}

#main_content table tr td select{
    font-family:Arial;
    width:100%;
}
```

Sorry about the lengthy post, It's just I've been stuck here for a long time..hehehe

Comment: I've solved this. but I didn't like the outcome..My solution is change the `#main_content table tr td input` into `#main_content>table>tr>td>input` any suggestion?..or my only solution is to create a seperate css file for IE7

Comment: I always do create separated files for ie. Sometimes two of them, one for ie6 one for ie7. It is much easier to deal with them this way than trying to find a markup which could've worked in 2006.

Comment: hehehe..can I use this conditional comment?? `[if IE 7]#main_content>table>tr>td>input`

Comment: Hacks are the developers choice - I don't see a problem with them. You can also use a `*` to target IE7, eg `*#main_cont...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Hacks thanks to @My Head Hurts. And also I'll try his suggestion of using asterisk(*) for IE7 css.